# Need assistance with pyqt logout

Tags: python, django, qt

I have problem with PyQt5 application and don't know how to solve it.

In my tray qt application I have my user logout action button which is connected with logout function. Logout function from **tray.py** should activate through response my logout function on server app in **views.py**. In **views.py** I have that logout function that receive back httpResponse("User is logged out").

My question is: "How to make aware my desktop pyqt app when user press that logout button? Because I recieve response.status_code = 200 it only means that i recieve just a page, and not that user state (if user is login or logout)". Everything seems to be ok, but dont know how to proceed execution of code in **tray.py**/logout()

desktop app - **tray.py**

```
import json
import sys, os, requests, uuid

from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMenu
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QSystemTrayIcon

from login import LoginForm
from settings import HTTP_PROTOCOL
from settings import SERVER_URL
from timestamp.form import TimestampForm



class SystemTrayIcon(QSystemTrayIcon):

    def __init__(self):
        QSystemTrayIcon.__init__(self)

        self.setIcon(QIcon('icons/icon-placeholder_128x128_red.png'))

        self.http_client = requests.Session()
        self.base_url = '{}://{}'.format(HTTP_PROTOCOL, SERVER_URL)
        self.set_desktop_timezone()


        # Keeping reference to LoginForm object so that window wouldn't close




        self.uuid = self.create_uuid('TTASM')
        self.create_private_key()

        try:
            requests.get(self.base_url)
            self.server_accessible = True
            self.present_login_form()
        except:
            self.server_accessible = False
            pass

        self.set_server_public_key()

        self.create_ui()

    def createURL(self, path):
        return '{}{}'.format(self.base_url, path)

    # Find Desktop's timezone   
    def set_desktop_timezone(self):
        response = requests.get('http://freegeoip.net/json')
        response_json = json.JSONDecoder().decode(response.text)
        self.timezone = response_json['time_zone']

    def verify_initial_data(self):
        url = self.createURL('/initial_synchronization/?timezone={}'.format(self.timezone))
        try:
            response = self.http_client.get(url)
            if response.status_code == 200:
                self.last_timestamp = response.text
            else:
                raise Exception('Server errror: {}'.format(response.status_code))
        except:
            print('Something is wrong with server comms')

    def set_server_public_key(self):
        #get server public key 

        url = self.createURL('/public_key/')
        print('Trying to get the public key from:', url) 

        try:
            response = self.http_client.get(url)
        except:
            print ('No response, server may be down')

        try:
            if response.status_code == 200:
                self.server_rsa_pub  = RSA.importKey(response.text)
                print ('Server private key aquired')
            else:
                print ('Server failed to provide public key')
        except:
            print("\nServer is not responding")
#             self.loginForm.close()

    def create_private_key(self):
        #Create new client RSA private key, public key and public key hash and store them to disk
        random_generator = Random.new().read
        self.client_rsa = RSA.generate(2048, random_generator)
        print ('Client private key created')

#         with open('./clientdata/client_RSA', 'wb') as f:
#             f.write(cl_rsa.exportKey())
#         with open('./clientdata/client_RSA.pub', 'wb') as f:
#             f.write(cl_rsa.publickey().exportKey())
#         with open('./clientdata/client_RSA.hash', 'w') as f:
#             f.write(SHA256.new(cl_rsa.publickey().exportKey()).hexdigest())

    print ('Client keys created')

    def create_ui(self):
        """Create user interface of Tray icon"""

        mainMenu = QMenu()
        subMenu = QMenu(mainMenu)
        subMenu.setTitle("Util")
        subButton_1 = subMenu.addAction("Show token")
        subButton_1.triggered.connect(self.show_token)
        subButton_2 = subMenu.addAction("Test sockets")
        subButton_2.triggered.connect(self.test_sockets)

        # Set the order of layout and add everything to main menu
        self.logInButton = mainMenu.addAction("Log in")
        self.logInButton.triggered.connect(self.present_login_form)

        self.simButton = mainMenu.addAction("Let's pretend server is accessible")
        self.simButton.triggered.connect(self.enable_login_etc)


        mainMenu.addSeparator()
        self.msgButton = mainMenu.addAction("Send message") # find a way how to hide this button to preserve action on it before user's log in action
        self.msgButton.triggered.connect(self.present_timestamp_form)

        if not self.server_accessible:
            self.logInButton.setEnabled(False)
            self.msgButton.setEnabled(False)


        mainMenu.addSeparator()
        mainMenu.addMenu(subMenu)
        mainMenu.addSeparator()
        self.logoutButton = mainMenu.addAction("Log out")
        self.logoutButton.triggered.connect(self.logout)
        self.logoutButton.setEnabled(False)
        mainMenu.addSeparator()
        exitButton = mainMenu.addAction("Exit")
        exitButton.triggered.connect(self.quit)


        self.setContextMenu(mainMenu)


    def enable_login_etc(self):
        self.logInButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.msgButton.setEnabled(True)

    def toggle_login_logout_button(self):
        self.logInButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.logoutButton.setEnabled(True)

    def create_uuid(self, UUID_string):
        return uuid.uuid3(uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS, UUID_string)

    def change_icon_on_login(self):
        self.setIcon(QIcon('icons/icon-placeholder_128x128_green.png'))

    def present_login_form(self):
        self.login_form = LoginForm(self)
        self.login_form.show()

    def present_timestamp_form(self):
        url = self.createURL('/last_activity_duration/')
        response = self.http_client.get(url)
        self.timestamp_form = TimestampForm(self, response.text)
        self.timestamp_form.show()

    def show_token(self):
        """Placeholder function"""

        try:
            self.showMessage('Token',
                             self.token,
                             QSystemTrayIcon.Information,
                             3000)
        except:
            self.showMessage('Token',
                             'No token received',
                             QSystemTrayIcon.Information,
                             3000)
    def test_sockets(self):
        """Placeholder function"""

        self.showMessage('Testing',
                         'Pending implementation',
                         QSystemTrayIcon.Information,
                         3000)

    #How to logout currently logged in user through get request
    def logout(self):
        url = self.createURL('/user_logout/')
        response = self.http_client.get(url)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            print("Response from view >>>>>>>", response.text)

          **WHAT TO DO HERE?**  


    def quit(self):
        """Exit program in a clean way."""
        if os.path.isfile('pid'):
            os.remove('pid') 
            print ("Deleting pid file")
        print ("Exiting")
        sys.exit(0)
```

Server app - **urls.py**

```
url(r'^user_logout/$', views.user_logout, name='user_logout'),
```

Server app - **views.py**

```
@verified_email_required  
def user_logout(request):
    print(request.user)
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponse('User is logged out')
```

my login.py. This is the way how I made user's login.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDesktopWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFormLayout, QHBoxLayout, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QLineEdit, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget



#from utility import encrypt_data

class LoginForm(QWidget):

def __init__(self, parent_tray):
    super(LoginForm, self).__init__()

    # keeping reference to parent
    self.parent_tray = parent_tray

    # define fixed size
    self.fixedWidth = 250
    self.fixedHeight = 100

    # no min, max, close button
    self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint |
                        QtCore.Qt.CustomizeWindowHint |
                        QtCore.Qt.WindowTitleHint)

    self.create_ui()
    self.move_to_primary_center()
    self.setWindowTitle("Log in")


def create_ui(self):
    """Create user interface for login popup window"""

    emailLabel = QLabel("Email:")
    passwordLabel = QLabel("Password:")
    self.email = QLineEdit()
    self.password = QLineEdit()
    print (self.email.whatsThis())

    self.email.setPlaceholderText("Enter your email")
    self.password.setPlaceholderText("Enter your password")



    # Show asterisk in input instead of password chars
    self.password.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)

    submitButton = QPushButton("Submit")

    # Usign lambda because Qt doesn't allow for arguments to by passed to slots
    # And we want to keep email and password as a private variables so we
    # don't want to make them direct members of Class and call them with self
    # directly inside self.submit() function
    submitButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.submit(self.parent_tray,
                                                     self.email.text(),
                                                     self.password.text()))

    # Enter pressed inside password line edit
    self.password.returnPressed.connect(lambda: self.submit(self.parent_tray,
                                                       self.email.text(),
                                                       self.password.text()))

    self.email.returnPressed.connect(self.password.setFocus)

    cancelButton = QPushButton("Cancel")
    cancelButton.clicked.connect(self.cancel)

    #Design a form layout
    formBox = QFormLayout()
    formBox.addRow(emailLabel, self.email)
    formBox.addRow(passwordLabel, self.password)

    # sign up label / link
    signUpLabel = QLabel()
    signUpLabel.setText('<a href="http://localhost:8000/sign-up/">Sign Up</a>')
    signUpLabel.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
    signUpLabel.show()

    # recover password link
    recoverLabel = QLabel()
    recoverLabel.setText('<a href="http://localhost:8000/recover-password/">Forgot your password?</a>')
    recoverLabel.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
    recoverLabel.show()

    # build sign up row
    signUpRow = QHBoxLayout()
    signUpRow.addWidget(signUpLabel)
    signUpRow.addWidget(recoverLabel)

    #add sign up row
    formBox.addRow(signUpRow)


    buttonRow = QHBoxLayout()
    buttonRow.addWidget(submitButton)
    buttonRow.addWidget(cancelButton)

    # add button row
    formBox.addRow(buttonRow)

    # Set layout for the Login Form (self)
    self.setLayout(formBox)

    try:
        last_user = open ('last_user', 'r').read()
        self.email.setText(last_user)
        self.password.setFocus()
    except:
        pass

    # Disable resize
    self.setFixedSize(self.fixedWidth, self.fixedHeight)

def move_to_primary_center(self):
    """Reposition window to center of primary screen"""

    desktop = QDesktopWidget()
    primaryScreenIndex = desktop.primaryScreen()
    rectScreenPrimarty = desktop.screenGeometry(primaryScreenIndex)

    # center in the middle of screen, considering window's own size
    self.move(rectScreenPrimarty.center().x() - self.fixedWidth/2,
              rectScreenPrimarty.center().y() - self.fixedHeight/2)


def submit(self, parentTray, email, password):
    """Send data to server."""

    if not email or not password:

        msgBox = QMessageBox()
        info_text = []
        if not email:
            info_text.append('Email cannot be empty!')
        if not password:
            info_text.append('Password cannot be empty!')

        joined_info_text = '\n \n'.join(info_text)

        msgBox.setInformativeText(joined_info_text)
        msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
        msgBox.setWindowTitle("Oops!")

        msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
        msgBox.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        msgBox.exec()

    else:
        url = parentTray.createURL('/accounts/login/')
        print('Trying to authenticate on', url)
        try:
            response = self.parent_tray.http_client.post(
                url,
                headers = {
                    'X-CSRFToken':self.parent_tray.http_client.cookies.get('csrftoken'),
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                data={
                    'login' : email,
                    'password' : password,
                    'client_public_key' : self.parent_tray.client_rsa.publickey().exportKey(),
                    'uuid' : parentTray.uuid
                }
            )
            print(parentTray.uuid)
        except Exception as e:
            print ('No response, server may be down')

        if response.status_code != 200:
            msgBox = QMessageBox()
            msgBox.setInformativeText('Invalid email and/or password')
            msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
            msgBox.setWindowTitle("Oops!")

            msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
            msgBox.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
            msgBox.exec()
            self.show()
            return False

        else: # if user logged in successfully
            parentTray.change_icon_on_login()
            parentTray.verify_initial_data()
            with open ('last_user' ,'w') as f:
                f.write(email) 
            self.parent_tray.showMessage('Success',
                 'You are logged in as {}'.format(email),
                 parentTray.Information,
                 3000)
            self.close()



def cancel(self):
    """Close password input"""
    self.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of an opinion question, it depends on how you want your application architecture(front and back ends) to operate.

If I were doing something along the lines of django as my backend for a desktop application I'd write it as an API and use JWOT authentication. This way my authentication state would be just using a token, which I can set the expiration limits on and every request would require this token as a form of authentication.

I don't see a login method just the form presentation, how exactly are you logging in the user and keeping track of that state? If you answer this it would be easier to answer the logout question.

Sorry for the answer, can't comment yet as per StackOverflow's *great* rules.